# What is the common reading of the word 外海?

Tags: word-choice, readings

外海 has two readings がいかい and そとうみ. What is the difference of the two? Personally, I am under the impression that がいかい is the common reading because of its similarity to the word 外国【がいこく】. However, I have encountered situations (some songs) where そとうみ has been used instead.

Comment: Poetry (like song lyrics) tends to bend linguistic rules in name of artistic freedom. So I wouldn't trust it as example of common language.

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/そとうみ listed as another reading of かいがい

Comment: @JACK I also first was confused between  海外 and 外海 (like Shanghai and Kaijo....). Anyway, considering 瀬戸内海 I think that even if it is read with naikai, I think it would at least be intuitive to use sotoumi for a "sea area distant from any islands" as contrast to naikai.

Comment: がいかい is correct, I mistakenly pronounced.

Comment: @JACK OK. And, I realize my logic in my comment also didn't make much sense, so, I will up-vote the question and wait and hope that someone will answer.... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The NHK Accent dictionary and the [大辞林](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A4%96%E6%B5%B7) include both がいかい and そとうみ readings as valid for this term.

The デジタル大辞泉 lists the first definition of *kaigai* and *sotoumi* as synonyms for a sea that is not bound by the continent, or to the open sea that is not close to the continent.
However, the second definition of *kaigai*, which is more metaphorical, means foreign lands, and I couldn´t find this connotation in the definitions of *sotoumi*. Here are the definitions for [がいかい](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A4%96%E6%B5%B7_%28%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84%29/#jn-35413)
and [そとうみ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A4%96%E6%B5%B7_%28%E3%81%9D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86%E3%81%BF%29/#jn-131002).

Additionally, there is the Buddhist term
[げかい](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A4%96%E6%B5%B7_%28%E3%81%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84%29/#jn-67403) that uses the same kanji.

Also, there is at least one person name with these kanji
([とのがい](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84)).

Comment: そとうみ is not the most used, but when used furigana comes along side most of the time (which is what furigana.info suggests). 海外 is read かいがい 99.9% of the time.

Comment: You´ve got a point, I will edit the answer.